# Chart colors are different on home page and report

Tags: charts, report-chart, lightning-home-page

[image]I'm doing a report with a chart and it displays a palette of color but on the home page with the same chart, colors are different.

Is there a way to colors been the same in both charts?

Comment: Can you elaborate more? Adding screenshot would be helpful.

Comment: Done, I added the image. thanks